# A question about three forcings

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Let $P_1$ be the finite support iteration of random forcings of length $\omega$. Let $P_2 = \text{Random} \times \text{Random}$ and $P_3 = \text{Random} \times \text{Cohen}$. Are $P_i, P_j$, for $1 \leq i < j \leq 3$, forcing isomorphic? All I know is that all of them add a $P_3$-generic.

Comment: So $\text{Random} \times \text{Random}$ is not the same as $\text{Random}$??

Comment: No. After adding one random real, the ground model measure algebra becomes sigma-centered, and forcing with it adds a Cohen real - in fact, $x+y$, where $(x, y)$ is $\text{Random} \times \text{Random}$-generic, is Cohen over $V$ (Random forcing does not add Cohen reals).

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen No, but $\mathrm{Random}*\dot{\mathrm{Random}}$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Random}$.

Comment: I don't recall the details but Tim Cookson looked at similar issues in his thesis: http://www.math.wisc.edu/~lempp/logic.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned in a comment, in a $P_2$-extension there are two random reals the sum of which is Cohen. However, forcing with **Cohen** over $V[\mathrm{Random}]$ doesn´t add any real that is random over $V$. So the sum of two random reals in a $P_3$-extension cannot be Cohen, since **Random** doesn´t add Cohen reals.

This argument can be found in [Perfect sets of random reals](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9209205.pdf) by Brendle and Judah, at the beginning of section 3.

Comment: Thanks! Theorem 2.1 in the paper "Around random algebra" by Judah and Shelah (listed in the reference of the Brendle Judah paper), shows that $P_1$ does not add random reals at stage $\omega$ so by the same argument it also follows that $P_1$ does not add $P_2$-generic. This only leaves the possibility of $P_1, P_3$ being isomorphic.

Comment: The Judah, Shelah result also shows that $P_1, P_3$ are not isomorphic since $V^{P_3}$ contains a random real $r$ such that $V^{P_3}$ does not contain any random real over $V[r]$.